# Generate a random duration

Tags: random, ada, duration

I want to know how to generate a random Duration in ada.

There is my code :

```
time : Duration;
time := 0.8;
```

How can I add a random value to `time` between 0.5 and 1.3 ?

Comment: I don't program in Ada, but surely Ada's standard library has a random number generator. A quick check turns up [this](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/rm12_w_tc1/html/RM-A-5-2.html)

Comment: @JohnColeman I found how to generate a random integer or float, but no duration. I don't know how it works.

Comment: That is a separate question -- how to convert floats (or integers) to duration. There probably is a conversion function for that purpose. I would be surprised if random duration can be achieved  in any other way then that of creating a random number then converting it.

Comment: Duration is fixed-point type, so you'll need a conversion. But that's easy: if f is a Float, Duration(f) is the conversion to the type Duration. NB: I'd avoid using "time" for your variable, as the name clashes with the type Time in Ada.Calendar. Nothing bad, just better avoiding confusion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is not quite as simple as one might hope. The Ada language provides random number generators for floating point types and for discrete types. The type Duration is a fixed point type.
The following code will generate a random duration in the range of 0.500 seconds to 1.300 seconds (with a random variability to the nearest millisecond).

```
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random;

procedure Main is

   Random_Duration : Duration;
   type Custom is range 500..1300;
   package Rand_Cust is new Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random(Custom);
   use Rand_Cust;
   Seed : Generator;
   Num  : Custom;
begin
   -- Create the seed for the random number generator
   Reset(Seed);

   -- Generate a random integer from 500 to 1300
   Num := Random(Seed);

   -- Convert Num to a Duration value from 0.5 to 1.3
   Random_Duration := Duration(Num) / 1000.0;

   -- Output the random duration value
   Put_Line(Random_Duration'Image);
end Main;
```

Comment: Fixed point types could be considered a flavor of discrete types... I thought it would work! Since it doesn't, isn't a curious omission not having a Fixed_Random variant in the Standard?

Comment: Fixed point types are considered a flavor of real types in Ada. Real types include fixed point types and floating point types. Ada classifies scalar types based upon the abstractions they support, not upon their physical representation.